# Unrecognized expression with jquery ui select plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.8.1 and am getting the following error below.  It is related to the jquery ui select plugin and originates from the second code snippet.

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li:not(.ui-selectmenu-group).slice(1,2)
```

***jquery-ui-select.js***

```
.bind('mouseout.selectmenu blur.selectmenu', function() {
    if ($(this).is(self._selectedOptionLi().selector)) { //<-- Originates here
        $(this).addClass(activeClass);
    }
    $(this).removeClass(self.widgetBaseClass + '-item-focus ui-state-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading to the latest version of [Selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu).  This resolved the issue for me when I upgraded our site to the latest jQuery release (1.8.3).  Seems like some old code in the selectmenu API that just never worked, and when upgrading jQuery, it starts throwing errors.